# Gitlab on Synology don't send confirmation email

Tags: gitlab, synology

I want to use Gitlab on my Synology DS1515+. So I downloaded gitlab toolkit from toolkit center, when finished, it directs me to a site with localhost: 192.168.x.xx:port/users/sign_in , I have to register an account, and attempted for many times, there is always no confirmation email sent to my outlook account. I also find some answers asking to config synology_gitlab.config file. also no use. 
What can I do? do I have to do other configurations, docker?redis?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: same problem here. Did you find a solution meanwhile?